# Transpose (Pivot)- convert rows to columns in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a series of family information and i wanted to transpose the information on a query. I am using PL/SQL Developer.

[image]

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2):

Provided you're using 11g or better, you could use `UNPIVOT` to achieve the result.

```
SELECT NAME, FAMILY, RELATION FROM TBL_FAMILY
UNPIVOT
((FAMILY, RELATION) FOR MEMBER IN (
 (FAMILY_1, FAMILY_1_REL), 
 (FAMILY_2, FAMILY_2_REL), 
 (FAMILY_3, FAMILY_3_REL)
 )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So long as you have a fixed number of columns in the source table, it works like this:

```
SQL> select * from repeating_group;

PERSON_N F FAMILY_1 F FAMILY_2 F FAMILY_3
-------- - -------- - -------- - --------
ANDREW   A Sister   B Father   C Brother
PAUL     Z Cousin   W Mother   Y InLaw


select
    person_name, family, relation
from
    (
        select person_name, family_1 as family, family_1_rel as relation from repeating_group
        union all
        select person_name, family_2 as family, family_2_rel as relation from repeating_group
        union all
        select person_name, family_3 as family, family_3_rel as relation from repeating_group
    ) x
order by 
    person_name;

PERSON_NAME   FAMILY RELATION
------------- ------ --------
ANDREW        A      Sister
ANDREW        B      Father
ANDREW        C      Brother
PAUL          W      Mother
PAUL          Y      InLaw
PAUL          Z      Cousin

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: This is not a good approach. Since Oracle 11.1 (we are at 12.2 now), there is the `unpivot` operator (illustrated in another Answer to this Question). Before 11.1, unpivoting was done with a cross-join to a small helper table. The difference is that both `unpivot` and the cross-join approach (the old version of unpivoting) require just one pass over the input data. The UNION ALL approach requires several passes, resulting in much slower performance.

Comment: Thank you guys/gals very much. This was very helpful. I ended up using the Union all not unpivot.

Comment: @mathguy.  I was interested in your assertion that the `union all` approach would be "much slower", so I tested it.  I had 199,362 source rows, so 577,086 target rows.  I ran 8 tests of each approach.  Both approaches take about 500ms after restarting the server, and 150ms for subsequent runs (cache primed, I presume).  So I see no difference in performance.  I think you underestimate the optimizer.

My conclusion is that both solutions are valid.  One is more portable, the other is a bit shorter to write.

Comment: @RonBallard - your comment about the optimizer is interesting (quite a different issue than caching; caching 200k source rows may not be too much, so "reading the base table n times" may really become "reading from disk once and the remaining times read from cache" - meaning not much loss of efficiency; but perhaps it won't work with 10 million rows, depending on cache size too). So - back to the optimizer: I would be surprised if it is smart enough to rewrite multiple union all as a single pivot operation of some sort. Did you look at the execution plans to compare? Cheers!